# 0x8badf00d exception on IOS App Submission

Tags: ios, crash

After multiple submission to the Apple IOS App store, we are consistently getting the same issue with a crash that is produced by the Apple Development Team, where as the application will load to a black screen, and remain there.

We've tried installing the application through iTunes, the version submitted, including uninstalling the original application, and installing the version.

The application does take a few seconds to start on the device, but by no means is killed by the WatchDog on the IOS device.

Here is the log sent back by the Apple dev:

```
    {
"app_name":"xxxxxxxxxx","app_version":"0.0.1","bundleID":"com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx","adam_id":913246800,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1 (12B410)","slice_uuid":"9da1b8cc-0937-34ab-8c05-99ce4fbb3650","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"0.0.1","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
 Incident Identifier: 4400ABD2-36CE-4DCA-AD08-2FC2B96DE97F
 CrashReporter Key:   55c42bd2dea3e9ef3e9a1516b09f6faf61eff2f8
 Hardware Model:      xxx
 Process:             xxxxxxxxxxx [208]
 Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4A599DE0-647E-45D0-A64A-71F4D1304A29/xxxxxxxxxx.app/xxxxxxxxxx
 Identifier:          com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx
 Version:             0.0.1 (0.0.1)
 Code Type:           ARM (Native)
 Parent Process:      launchd [1]

 Date/Time:           2014-11-03 09:32:18.490 -0800
 Launch Time:         2014-11-03 09:31:55.586 -0800
 OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B410)
 Report Version:      105

 Exception Type:  00000020
 Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
 Highlighted Thread:  0

 Application Specific Information:
 <BKNewProcess: 0x13661f330; com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx; pid: 208> has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
 {(
     <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1365252e0> id: 47-3E8D0C34-2AC8-4F69-A46C-857A6AF5E0B5 name: Suspending process: <BKNewProcess: 0x13661f330; com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx; pid: 208> permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner pid:47 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI  preventSuspendOnSleep 
 )}

 Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 14.270 (user 14.270, system 0.000), 65% CPU 
 Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 5.347, 24% CPU

 Last Exception Backtrace:
 (0x2a15fc1f 0x37d14c8b 0x2a164f55 0x2a162f57 0x2a094df8 0x1701008 0x265740 0x1e7890 0x10fd6fc 0x1d782d8 0x1e1a588 0x18c67b0 0x1970bf8 0x1970bc4 0x1971434 0x19641fc 0x19663d0 0x1966610 0x18af3fc 0x18af454 0x1966398 0x198f7e4 0x198f764 0x198f6ac 0x1992fa8 0x1945b90 0x1945bf0 0x1939d04 0x1938cc8 0x1939518 0x1936a30 0x1732318 0x171179c 0x2ae63f99 0x2a1262a7 0x2a125e23 0x2a124073 0x2a072211 0x2a072023 0x314110a9 0x2d67e1d1 0xe61cc 0xe6118)

 Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
 Thread 0:
 0   xxxxxxxxxx                        0x01d87fcc 0xe2000 + 30040012
 1   xxxxxxxxxx                        0x01d87cc4 0xe2000 + 30039236
 2   xxxxxxxxxx                        0x01d89054 0xe2000 + 30044244
 3   xxxxxxxxxx                        0x01da5a14 0xe2000 + 30161428
 4   libsystem_platform.dylib          0x383d4879 0x383d0000 + 18553
 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x383d8d33 0x383d5000 + 15667
 6   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x382fa905 0x382b0000 + 305413
 7   libc++abi.dylib                   0x376389c5 0x37638000 + 2501
 8   libc++abi.dylib                   0x3765266d 0x37638000 + 108141
 9   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x37d14f23 0x37d0e000 + 28451
 10  libc++abi.dylib                   0x3764fde1 0x37638000 + 97761
 11  libc++abi.dylib                   0x3764f8ab 0x37638000 + 96427
 12  libobjc.A.dylib                   0x37d14dcf 0x37d0e000 + 28111
 13  CoreFoundation                    0x2a0722a9 0x2a05a000 + 98985
 14  CoreFoundation                    0x2a07201f 0x2a05a000 + 98335
 15  GraphicsServices                  0x314110a5 0x31408000 + 37029
 16  UIKit                             0x2d67e1cd 0x2d610000 + 451021
 17  xxxxxxxxx                       0x000e61c8 0xe2000 + 16840
 18  xxxxxxxxx                        0x000e6114 0xe2000 + 16660

 Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
 Thread 1:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x383472a0 0x38346000 + 4768
 1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x382809fd 0x38273000 + 55805
 2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x3827620f 0x38273000 + 12815
```

If anyone has seen or solved an issue similar to this one, please let me know, it was hard to find any information related to both an issue similar to this related to Unity.

Comment: 0x8BADF00D ("ate bad food") is used by Apple in iOS crash reports, when an application takes too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events.

Comment: At least that's better than 0xDEADBEEF

Comment: You should consider changing your app design when it takes multiple seconds to start without giving the user any feedback. How about an introduction screen showing some kind of a loading indicator like many games do?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, as it turns out, Apple was being sent an older version of the application, and had depreceated code within it that caused a crash at the start, as opposed to what we were seeing at the time